# what is the difference between kotlin ..< operator and until operation for ranges

Tags: android, kotlin

in kotlin 1.9.0 `..<` is stable

what is the difference between **`..<`** and `until` operator in kotlin ?
in kotlin documentation it is declared that if you use `until` you might make mistake but with `..<` you won't.
i don't understand how.

here is the [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew19.html#stable-operator-for-open-ended-ranges) to kotlin documentation

Comment: "If you use the `until` infix function, it's easy to make the mistake of assuming that the upper bound is included". What's unclear with that statement?

Comment: so all it is saying is that developer's eye it is more comfortable to use ..< rather that until? @Rogue

Comment: It's less about comfort and more about clarity. If you see `2..<10`, think of it like "ranging from 2 until `<10`", it's an indicator that the `10` is _not_ included (so 2,3,...,8,9). `2 until 10` makes an implication that 10 is included (i.e. 2,3,...,8,9,10), but this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `..<` operator adds significant new capabilities that weren't possible with `until`. It allows true open-ended ranges to be used with all comparable types, including floating point numbers.

The `until` function is only defined for integer types (Int, Long, Short, etc.). The ranges it creates are actually always implemented as closed ranges. When you write `x until y`, the implementation simply calls through to `x .. (y - 1)`.

That works for integers, because we can define every open integer range as an equivalent closed range. We know that the largest value in `x ..< y` is always going to be `y - 1`.

However, it doesn't work for floating point numbers. What's the largest value in the range `0.0 ..< 1.0`? Is it `0.9`? Why not `0.99`? There is no largest value, so we can't express this open range as an equivalent closed range.

It also doesn't work for other comparable types that aren't numbers. You can't define the open range `"cat" ..< "dog"` as a closed range, because you can't calculate `"dog" - 1`.

The `until` function was a way to "fake" open-end ranges by converting them to an equivalent closed range. The new `..<` operator allows us to express real open-ended ranges for all comparable types, without converting to a closed range.

Comment: Technically, for fixed precision floating point types like Double and Float, I suppose you _could_ determine the largest number less than a given value, but that'd be a pretty horrible way of doing things. This way is much nicer, and works for BigDecimals too.

Answer (score 3):

For integral types (Int, Long, Char, Byte), there is no difference at all. Both `..<` and `until` produce ranges that are both ClosedRanges and also the new OpenRange type. But `..<` can also be used with any other Comparable type to create specifically an OpenRange.

The [KEEP design document](https://github.com/kotlin/KEEP/blob/open-ended-ranges/proposals/open-ended-ranges.md) states that Jetbrains conducted a study and found that misinterpretations of whether the range was inclusive or exclusive was reduced by about 20-30% when comparing `until` with `..<`. So there is data supporting that mistakes are made and can be reduced, but we can only guess at the reasons people might misinterpret `until`.

I will not be surprised if they eventually deprecate `until` and remove it from the language. There is a general language design goal in Kotlin to avoid redundancies that lead to language bloat, which contributes to code being less readable overall.

Other than reducing errors in interpreting and writing code, the other benefits are the new OpenRange concept and the symmetry of using an operator for both closed and open ranges. Users often were typing out `1..(x - 1)` even though convention preferred `until`, probably because of a desire for symmetry or because of familiarity with using an operator for it.

Comment: I suppose now some people will think the operator for closed ranges is `..<=` 